# How to export a specific csv file text?

Tags: export, text, csv-format

I have a data set of text in string format as

```
data = {{{"To say lion in portuguese speak leão"}, {"text 1"}}, {{"To say Hello in portuguese speak Olá"}, {"Text 2"}}, {{"To say assembly in portuguese speak assembléia"}, {"Text 3"}}, {{"To say production in portuguese speak produção"}, {"Text 4"}}, {{"To say criation in portuguese speak criação"}, {"Text 5"}}};
```

I would like to export the data as a CSV text file in two column, without quotation mark and curly brackets {"text"}.

The text has special character, so I used `CharacterEncoding -> "ISOLatin1"`. I have tested the following code:

```
Export["data.csv", data, "CSV", 
  "TextDelimiters" -> None, CharacterEncoding -> "ISOLatin1"];
```

which return a document as shown below

[image]

However, I expected something like

[image]

Please, can anybody help me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to structure your data so that it is 2 dimensional. Right now, it's got extra levels. So when you export, it's only interpreting the upper levels as the "data" for the csv. Try something like `csvData = Flatten[data, {{1, 3}}]` and then export the `csvData`.

Comment: @lericr thank you. Your suggestion solve partial of the problem, removing quotation and curly. However, how to structure the table in two columns?

Comment: When I tried it, I got two columns. But I elided the options, because they seemed unecessary. When I added them back in, yeah, the data was weird. So, just remove the TextDelimiters option. I can't find any documentation on that anyway, so how did you come up with it?

Comment: lericr's comment is correct. But there has been a failure in communications. Spreadsheets are two dimensional. Your data are three dimensional. That mismatch is causing your problem.  O comentário de lericr está correto. Mas houve uma falha nas comunicações. As planilhas são bidimensionais. Seus dados são tridimensionais. Essa incompatibilidade está causando o seu problema.